# Fast approach to read and parse serial-data continuously

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port, buffer

I've got a thread to read and parse serial data.
The messages are in binary format and start with either the character 'F', 'S', 'Q' or 'M'.
There are no newlines and there is no special ending character (the characters above state that a message is finished and everything before it is ready to be parsed).

How do I continuously read and parse the data?

All that comes to my mind is having a 4096 byte long input buffer (byte array) and then follow this procedure:

- Track the position in the buffer manually
- append available data to it via `SerialPort.Read(buffer, position, byteCount)`
- try to parse as many messages as possible from the buffer
- copy the rest to a temporary buffer
- reset the input buffer
- copy the contents of the temporary buffer to the original buffer
- set the position in the buffer

**Can you think of faster / easier approaches?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very simple way to get ahead is to stop trying to make it faster.  There is no point, serial port data rates are very, very low and modern computers are very, very fast.  Your `Read()` call only ever returns a single byte, rarely 2.

Note that this is hard to see, when you debug and single-step through the code then you'll artificially slow down your program a great deal.  Allowing more bytes to be received and thus more of them getting returned by the `Read()` call.  But this doesn't happen when the program runs at normal speed.

So use `SerialPort.BaseStream.ReadByte()` instead.  Makes the code *very* simple.

Comment: Won't I risk missing bytes with `ReadyByte()`? How do I determine that there's nothing else to read? Why would I prefered `BaseStream.ReadyByte()` over `Read()`?

Comment: It is ReadByte(), not ready.  There is no risk.  You use BaseStream because SerialPort does not have a method to read a single byte, you can use Read() with a *count* of 1 if you really want to.  BytesToRead tells you how many are available.

Comment: and why would you prefer it over `Read(buffer, 0, SerialPort.BytesToRead)`?

Comment: Because then you have to deal with reading too many.  Only thing you can do wrong is not trying it.

Comment: As soon as I detect one of the characters in question (F, S, Q, M) I'd have to read a fixed amount of bytes anyways but this works either way.
 What I'm more worried about is after reading almost everything that's available it starts reading a new packet which is not fully transmitted yet so it will be corrupt. Is that possible or will they always be fully transmitted?

Comment: This is especially something you cannot get wrong when you read a single byte at a time.  You don't start processing the bytes you've received until you get the next letter.  Try it.

Answer (score 2):

After acquiring some experience with SerialPort C# component

At the beginning: Take a serial port exclusevily.

Then:

1st parallel Task: Continues read **entire** buffer content after a **regular** 
interval and pushes the read chunk into a *"Gathering Collection"*  of data.

2nd parallel Task: Analyzes the *"Gathering Collection"* for a completed *"phrase"*, delegates the clonned *"phrase"* to a *"Phrase Manager"* and excludes the phrase from the *"Gathering Collection"*

You have a freedom about *"Gathering Collection"* implementation, but what was important to me is that:

- read **all**, but not a sized content from the Serial port buffer
- to avoid losses and save an order in messages build your own port dispatcher rather let anybody open and close your port at any time for reading/writing.
- detect the port read frequency experimenally. The more frequent read-operation will let your code detect fatser a *"phrase"* and start the proder handlind. Too frequent reading without detecting a *"phrase"* can cost you additional resource usage.